# Lookahead vs lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a hard time to understand the concepts of "lookahead" and "lookbehind". For example, there is a string "aaaaaxbbbbb".
If we look at "x", does lookahead mean looking "x" towards "bbbbb" or "aaaaa"? I mean the direction.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I still don't understand it, I would like use example to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the regex is `x(?=insert_regex_here)` that is a (positive) look*ahead*, which looks *ahead*, or *forwards*, in other words towards "bbbb".
It means "find an x that is *followed by* `insert_regex_here`".

If the regex is `(?<=insert_regex_here)x` that is a (positive) look*behind*, which looks *behind*, or *backwards*, in other words towards "aaaa". It means "find an x that is *preceded by* `insert_regex_here`".

You can also have negative lookahead `x(?!insert_regex_here)` meaning "`x` *not* followed by `insert_regex_here`", and negative lookbehind `(?<!insert_regex_here)x`, meaning "x *not* preceded by `insert_regex_here`".

(The above `(?=` and `(?<!`  etc are Perl regex syntax - the syntax might be slightly different depending on your flavour of regex).

I recommend you read the link that Chad gave in the comments. **It has examples.**

Comment: Erm. Those examples you gave were negative/positive lookbehind, and the first example lost a `<` :P Positive/negative lookahead would be without that first `<`. (also, the presence of all those angle brackets gets especially confusing :P)

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant `(?=<` not `(?=<`. I'm going to remove those `<>` around, they *are* confusing :P

Comment: This syntax is a bit of a strange beast : the name obviously gives you the direction where the engine looks. But the syntax feels like duplication of information : when you want to look behind, you already write the zero-width match **behind** what you want to match, why is the engine also requiring a different operator ? (It is an actual question, in a comment  ; )

Comment: @AdN The problem is that look behinds must be fixed length, while lookahead can be variable length (or at least, most implementations do so) If you don't distinguish them syntactically you end up with incorrect results.

Comment: I'm not very good at English. How would you define "be followed by" explicitly in a left-to-right writing system?