# Regex, excluding parts of expression in split

Tags: regex, string, split

I have the following regex expression: `[\S](?!\s)[\W][\S]`, 
It will match patterns like: `z.A`,
 I want to split strings like so:
 `"The brown fox.Jumped over the..."=> ["The brown fox.","Jumped over the..."]` - That is why I am using that regex, but my problem is how can I exclude the [\S] (in my example: "J" (-from jumped)) yet know it is there for the regex to be valid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might be looking for a lookahead:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

[Lookahead vs lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621273/lookahead-vs-lookbehind)